# How to use the watch in api.ListOptions with client-go the client SDK of kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to watch the change of namespaces in kubernetes cluster, with code like:

```
        log.Infoln("====== 1 ======= ")
        namespaces, err := clientset.Namespaces().List(api.ListOptions{Watch: true})
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorln("Get namespaces from kubernetes cluster error:%v", err)
        }
        log.Infoln("====== 2 ======= ")
        for _, namespace := range namespaces.Items {
            log.Println("=======>> namespaces: ", namespace)
        }
```

this code will block at `namespaces, err := clientset.Namespaces().List(api.ListOptions{Watch: true})`. But there is no response when I create new namespace either delete the namespaces.

the `client-go` is `k8s.io/client-go/1.5/`

Anyone can give me the example code for this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had foud the answer:

```
var watch watch.Interface
if watch, err = clientset.Namespaces().Watch(api.ListOptions{Watch: true}); err != nil {
    log.Errorln("Watch namespaces from kubernetes cluster error:%v", err)
    return
}

eventChan := watch.ResultChan()
for event := range eventChan {
    log.Infoln(event)
}
```